# matrix setscale zoom effecting calling activity

Tags: android, matrix, zooming

I have a main activity that's ondraw method is in in a separate class called Drawit. The Drawit class extends View.

From the main activity I call:

```
drawn=true;
di.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
ll1.addView(di);
```

where ll1 is the top level linearlayout of the main activity & di is the Drawit class.

In the Ondraw method in Drawit class I draw images, lines, text etc which all draw fine and then call

```
drawMatrix = mycanvas.getMatrix();
```

where drawMatrix is my matrix and mycanvas is canvas.

In my onTouchEvent of the Drawit class I have this which I thought should zoom the whole view when touched

```
drawMatrix.setScale(1.25f, 1.25f, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
mycanvas.concat(drawMatrix);
super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

However nothing appears to happen until I press back, which calls onbackpress in the main activity

```
if (drawn==true){
    ll1.removeView(di);
    drawn=false;
}else{
    finish();   
}
```

Then I discover the zoom has been effecting the main activity and not the canvas as expected.

It's probably going to be something simple but after trying everything I can think off for several hours I'm getting nowhere

Any advice welcomed, thanks

Comment: you need to call canvas.concat in onDraw method

Comment: Thanks, Just tried that and it doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: try in onDraw: m = new Matrix(); m.setScale(3, 3); canvas.concat(m); drawing code follows...

Comment: drawMatrix = mycanvas.getMatrix();
//drawMatrix = new Matrix(); 
drawMatrix.setScale(3, 3); 
mycanvas.concat(drawMatrix);
in onDraw has no effect on canvas but does not change main activity zoom

Comment: try this http://pastebin.com/a0389jh7

Comment: thanks for the example, Perhaps I expect it work differently. In your example you are doing another canvas.drawLine after applying matrix. I was expecting to be able to apply matrix after all drawing is complete so that existing drawn canvas would be zoomed. Otherwise I would would be redrawing the whole view which takes several seconds. Do I have to redraw the view to zoom it?

Comment: it works that way, your drawing code will be affected only if you concat the canvas before, not aftet